# How can I debug js code using Cordova and ios simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am using xcode 4.5.2 and PhoneGap (Cordova) to develop an iphone app.

Looking at the `Log Navigator` in xcode does not show me any of the js `console.log`s.

What must I do to be able to see these log outputs?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This may be a little late but its quite simple.

So in Safari, Go `preferences` -> `advanced` -> `Show Develop menu in menu bar`. Once you've that, build and run in xcode and then in safari go `Develop` -> `iPhone Simulator` -> `Your App Name`.

It works pretty well but I can't find a way to make it persist as such, so you need to repeat this after every run seemingly, which is a pain. If I find a way I'll post here.

Additional:

As Harry points out below in the comments, you can then run `location.reload` in the safari console to reload the Cordova app and see all the log messages from the boot of the application

Comment: For anyone coming here late... you can then run `location.reload` in the safari console to reload the Cordova app and see all the log messages from the boot of the application

Comment: Or just hit Cmd-R to reload

Comment: I'm aware this answer is old, but does anyone else find that the simulator (or a connected device) sometimes just drop out of the `Develop` menu?

Comment: `location.reload()` in the console does the job to identify annoying errors, thank you Harry

Comment: The problem with this method is that you cannot debug the startup process of the app, when the option appears in Safari, it's too late to debug the startup process.

Comment: @andreszs See Harry's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I found a little help to open the console for ios simulator

http://blog.persistent.info/2014/06/adding-keyboard-shortcuts-for.html